# f interpolation doesn't reduce the number of digits in scala

Tags: scala

**Usecase**:

length of number > 5 => return first 5 digits.

length of number = 5 => return the number as is.

length of number < 5 => add leading zeros to the number.

number is -ve => return 00000

**My Code:**

```
object ScalaCodes {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(intToString(123))
    println(intToString(1))
    println(intToString(12345))
    println(intToString(123456789))
    println(intToString(0))
    println(intToString(-10))
  }
  def intToString(i:Int): String = {
    if(i < 0)
      "0"*5
    else
      f"$i%05d"
  } 
}
```

The output is:

```
00123
00001
12345
123456789
00000
00000
```

Why is 123456789 not reducing to 5 digits.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect `123456789` to be "truncated" to 5 digits?

Comment: I have edited my question [Gaël J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j) ...I want to return fist 5 digits only if the length is more than 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *"first 5 digits"* try:

```
if (i > 99999) f"$i%.5s"
```

---

Or a simple one-liner. No `if`...`else if`... required.

```
f"${i max 0}%05d".take(5)
```

Comment: Thanks [jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh)... I was trying to return the first 5 digits only.
This was perfect. Kudos!!!

Comment: Love the 2nd one....[jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh)....totally functional..Thnx